# Passing query string to ModelForm hidden field - Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I want to pass a query string e.g., `?refcode='A1234'` to a hidden field called `inbound_referral_code` in a ModelForm.

My model is as follows:

```
class User(models.Model):
   email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, blank=False, unique=True)
   inbound_referral_code = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

My ModelForm is currently as follows:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
   model = User
   fields = ['email', 'inbound_referral_code']
   widgets = {'inbound_referral_code': forms.HiddenInput()}
```

My View is:

```
def register(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
      form = UserForm(request.POST)
      [...]
   else:
      form = UserForm()
      return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': form})
```

And my template is currently:

```
<form action="{% url 'register' %}" method="post">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{ form.as_p }}
   <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Two questions:

- How do I assign `?refcode` parameter to `inbound_referral_code` field?
- What happens if `?refcode` isn't provided?

Comment: Is your problem that you don't know how to set the `inbound_referral_code` when rendering, or that you don't know how to read it after the post?

Comment: Actually I don't understand either of those! I will update question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combining the different answers, the following solution worked:

Set the "initial" value of the form parameter, and ensure the template renders with the bound form if validation fails. The correct view function is:

```
def register(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
      form = UserForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
         return redirect([...])
   else:
      refcode = request.GET.get('refcode')
      form = UserForm(intial={'inbound_referral_code': refcode)

   return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': form})
```

Note that the bottom `return render(...)` needed to be moved so that it is also called with the form from the POST request if it contains validation errors...

Answer (score 1):

To assign the `refcode`, you need to pass it into the form, so you pass in something other than request.POST that contains it, change it before

```
dict = request.POST.copy()
dict["inbound_referral_code"] = request.POST.get("refcode")
form = UserForm(dict)
# ...
```

or after validating:

```
if form.is_valid():
    form.cleaned_data["inbound_referral_code"] = request.POST.get("refcode")
```

If it isn't provided, you can check for that and pass a custom value, or set a default when defining the form/model.

---

To set it in the template, you can pass an initial value

```
else:
  form = UserForm(initial={"inbound_referral_code": "ref-value-here"})
  return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Ok - I am currently doing that, however I have modified the first block of code to work on GET (not POST).   However, by doing this, the template is already throwing up a "this field is required" error on the email field immediately...

Comment: If you want the email to be optional, you can define it in your form and pass required=False

Comment: No the issue isn't the email being optional - it is definitely required. The issue is I need to pass refcode to the form on a GET request... Given the current implementation it results in validation errors being thrown before the user has even tried to enter any data...